# c++ template do not work

Tags: c++, templates

```
//class template
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T> class Pair{
        T value1,value2;
    public:
        Pair(T first,T second){
            value1 = first;
            value2 = second;
        }       
        T getMax();     
};

template<class T> 
T Pair::getMax(){
    T max;
    max = (value1 > value2) ? value1 : value2;
    return max; 
}

int main(){
    Pair my(100,200);
    cout << my.getMax() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

when I run the program,the problem occur:

```
[Error] F:\c#\cplusplus\demo_code\demo11_template2.cpp:16: error: `template<class T> class Pair' used without template parameters
```

the place where occur the problem is  in the line of "T Pair::getMax(){";

```
[Error] F:\c#\cplusplus\demo_code\demo11_template2.cpp:18: error: `value1' was not declared in this scope
[Error] F:\c#\cplusplus\demo_code\demo11_template2.cpp:18: error: `value2' was not declared in this scope
```

the place where occur the problem is  in the line of `max = (value1 > value2) ? value1 : value2;`

why cause the problem? I hope to get help sincerely,thanks!

I am poor in english,very sorry!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write the function definition as

```
template<class T> 
T Pair<T>::getMax(){
    T max;
    max = (value1 > value2 ? value1 : value2 );
    return max; 
}
```

Also variable max is not used. You could write simply

```
template<class T> 
T Pair<T>::getMax(){
    return value1 > value2 ? value1 : value2; 
}
```

Usually if two values are equal then the first value is selected as the maximum. So I would write the function like

```
template<class T> 
T Pair<T>::getMax(){
    return value1 < value2 ? value2 : value1; 
}
```

And a class can not deduce its template parameters. So you need to write

```
Pair<int> my(100,200);
```

Comment: Why not just `return value1 > value2 ? value1 : value2` ?

Comment: @Wojtek Surowka I could answer why do not use std::max?:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Assuming the OP is creating this code as a learning exercise, "use `std::max`" will not help in this, but "you can skip the `max` variable" still teaches them something.

Comment: @Angew This variable is important that correctly to write the conditional operator in learning purpose.:)

Answer (score 2):

`Pair` is a template, not a type, so where you need a type you have to specify it thus:

```
template<class T>
T Pair<T>::getMax()
      ^^^
```

and thus:

```
Pair<int> my(100,100);
```